# UILocalNotification no me suma correctamente applicationIconBadgeNumber en cambio de día

Tags: ios, objective-c

No acabo de entender como funciona el incremento del Badge del ios.

Con el código que pongo a continuación me sale la notificación correcta, pero al pasar un día en vez de poner, por ejemplo de 0 a 1, me pasa a 2...

No entiendo que me dejo o como ios incrementa este valor.

¿Me podéis echar un mano?

```
UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

localNotification.fireDate = startDate; // Por ejemplo: Ponemos el día siguiente a las 09:00 de la mañana
localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
localNotification.alertBody =  @"Tiene tareas pendientes para realizar";
localNotification.alertAction = descripcionTextField.text;
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;

NSDictionary *inventory = @{
             @"AcID" : [NSNumber numberWithInt: acuarioSeleccionadoID],
             @"TareaID" : [NSNumber numberWithInt: tareaSeleccionada],
             };

localNotification.userInfo= inventory;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ese contador lo has de controlar tú, es decir, o en local o del lado del servidor. iOS no "autoincrementara" el contador si le llegan nuevas notificaciones.
Por tanto, tienes dos formas de hacerlo:

1. Cuando recibes la notificación en local, coges el contador actual y lo incrementas en 1
2. Lo gestionas desde el servidor (esta es la más correcta)

Comment: Tienes algun código que me guie en como controlar la notificación desde el servidor.

Comment: No, cada aplicación/servidor es distinta. Básicamente, debes saber qué notificaciones has enviado y cuantas ha leído el cliente. Con eso, muestras las pendientes de leer.

Comment: Ok, lo he estado mirando y entiendo lo que dices, gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Por las pruebas que he estado realizando, llego a la conclusión siguiente:

Cuando ponemos al crear una UILocalNotification:

```
<code>
localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;
</code>
```

Estamos diciendo que, con el numero de bagde que tenemos en este momento le sumaremos uno.

Esto quiere decir que, si en unas horas lanzamos 2 notificaciones al usuario, la primera pondrá el badge a uno, pero la segunda también, ya que al principio, cuando se creo el badge estaba a cero. Cuando esperamos que hubiera puesto 2.

Como ha puesto mhergon, si queremos controlar el badge deberemos de gestionarlo nosotros desde un servidor.

Espero que os sirva de ayuda.